# Computed property throws error at initialization

Tags: ractivejs

(ref http://jsfiddle.net/kapLv0mt/4/)

I have

```
Member = Ractive.extend({
  template : "<div>{{name}}</div>",
  computed : {male : function(){this.get('gender')=='m'}}
})

ff = new Ractive({
  el : '#container',
  template : "there are {{male_count}} males{{#family}}<member/>{{/family}}",
  components : {member : Member},
  data : {family : [
      {name:'Fred',gender:'m'},
      {name:'Wilma',gender:'f'},
      {name:'Rocky',gender: 'm'},
      {name:'Bubbles',gender: '?'}
  ]},
  computed : { male_count : function(){
    return _(this.findAllComponents('member')).filter(function(mem){return mem.get('male')}).length;
   }
  }
})
```

An error is thrown during ractive initialization, and also the computed property "male_count" does not return the correct value. The initialization error results from the property being included in the template, but even then the computed property does not return the correct value, probably since it was incorrectly computed at initialization.

How can I initialize a Ractive object attribute that depends on components?

Edit:
Based on a responder's suggestion, I'll mention here that the code example is very much simplified from my actual code. The component filter algorithm in the actual code is based on about 9 comparison criteria, including dates, text matches, numerical ranges, where the thresholds are input via the UI for a list filter. For this reason, I would like to stick with the idea (as in the example) of the filter test being implemented in the component.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't even need to inquire the `member` component to count the males in the data. The data is already in the parent component, the computed is *also* in the parent component. Why not just inquire *to itself*?

```
computed: {
    male_count: function () {
        return this.get('family').filter(function (familyMember) {
            return familyMember.gender === 'm'
        }).length;
    }
}
```

It's also a good thing to keep in mind that in Ractive, you operate on the data, not on DOM (or in this case, components). Once you start using DOM operations, or finding components, your design needs some rethinking.

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph the Dreamer. Yes, that will work for the simple case. I oversimplified my problem for SO. Probably too much. What I actually have is a complex, multi-attribute dynamic matching algorithm in the filter (dates, numeric ranges, text matches etc). For this reason, I need the component to "own" the filter algorithm, as in my code, above, else the code becomes harder to reason about.

Comment: I thought about your design comment, @JtD. A component is a DOM fragment associated with a subset of the page data. It can/should have its own behaviours. It makes perfect sense to me that it should include itself (or not) in the DOM based on criteria applied to its associated data, and not delegate that decision up to a parent. Root Ractive instances would become unwieldy if they managed the whole page.

Comment: @LesNightingill Well, yeah. There will be times where encapsulating functionality in a component makes sense. But in the context of this example (which SO answers should be in), however, it's just making an unnecessary round trip. Might be worth mentioning in the post the complexity that warrants a component to enclose that logic.